# How to increase and decrease the height of the custom cell in TableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am new to iphone development. I am using custom tableview cell. In that I have to increase and decrease the custom cell height based upon the condition. I have increased but while increasing the custom cell the main tableview also increases. I need to increase only the custom cell. Below I have shown the code what I have used.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"test"];
    if (!cell) {
        cell= [[TableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"test"];
    }
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    // Configure the cell...
    return cell;
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   int testvalue=1;
   if(testvalue == 1) {
      return 45;
   } else {
      return 100;
   }
}
```

[Here I have attached screenshot.both main tableview and custom cell height is increasing. I don't want to increase main tableview cell height.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHCuO.png)

Comment: `testvalue` will only ever have a value of `1` so the `if/else` is pointless. `heightForRowAtIndexPath` can only ever return `100` given your current code. And that will apply to every row.

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: After your edit, all of your rows will have a height of 45. It's still the same issue.

Comment: actually the cell height is increasing. but it increases main table view also. I don't want to increase main tableview.

Comment: Actually you don't get the concept of UITableview. First you are always returning TableViewCell from method cellForRowAtIndexPath, you also need to return UITableViewCell. Secondly you can never put check like testvalue in tableview scenario because UITableView is reusing cells to show information on screen. Try to put Indexpath.row check and also please check this tutorial for basic concepts.
https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all , I would highly recommend to use **UITableViewAutomaticDimension** for your tableView , so that you dont have to worry about the cell size.

Now, as per your requirement, you want to change cell size for certain conditions, so you can do something like this:

- Take one base view in cell which will have all other views as
  subview.
- Give height constraint to this base view and take outlet of that
  height constraint.
- Now when you want to increase or decrease the height, simply change
  the height constarint constant value like
  `your_height_constraint.constant = your_new_value`

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I have tried what you said. Base view gets increase and decrease.but Cell height is in constant height. I want to increase the cell height also.

Comment: Have you applied proper constraints ? Use leading,trailing,top and bottom constraints to the base view.

Comment: ya I have applied the proper constrain. The base view is increasing and decreasing. but cell height gets constant.

Comment: To increase the cell height I have used [ _mytableview.rowHeight = 220;] this code. it works fine. thank you.

Comment: @Kk_Pd Happy to hear that. Cheers..Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

How I did was by Animating last view bottom constraints

```
func showOrHide() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
            if !self.isExpanded {
                self.heightConstraint?.constant = 0
                self.isExpanded = true

            } else {
                self.heightConstraint?.constant = 150
                self.isExpanded = false
            }
            self.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
```

And then calling beginUpdates and endUpdates on tableview adjust cell height else sinking will not work

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.showOrHide()

        tableview.beginUpdates()
        tableview.endUpdates()
    }
```